# feed data to remote SSH linux script through putty/plink that were launch by vb.net

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, vb.net, plink

I am stucked thinking to send data to the SSH linux script while it is running in plink with vb.net.

I am able to get the output & surely able to execute the SSH linux script with standardiput.writeline and standardoutput.readline.

But, the problem is that the SSH linux script need user input y/n during the script execution. I saw some examples but mostly on Linux programming that preset the input. But, I cannot preset the input. I need user to define y/n.

I tried standardinput.writeline("y") but, this command doesn't looks like doing what I want. Any suggestion please?

Thanks!

Comment: If `standardinput.writeline` works for you for entering command on command prompt, it should work equally for answering the question. What does happen when you do the `standardinput.writeline("y")`?

Comment: I had actually feeding the output to a textbox and I notice something like this: Does the display turn off? [y/n] y. You see that with the standardinput.writeline("y") had actually input a "y" there or probably not. But, it is surely not merely a "y". Because after the standardinput.writeline("y"), the .sh ended with result as if a "n" or something else is entered and not a "y".

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, can you please help me on this? I don't have any idea at all about this...

Comment: What do you mean by "textbox"? That sound ike a GUI, not a terminal prompt. Can you include a sample of the console/terminal display in your question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Because I will input the "y" or "n" only when the .sh question arose. So, I am checking the output with StandardOutput.ReadLine(). Rather than using writeline, I try to input two times with standardinput.write("y") then follows by standardinput.write(vbLf). I think problem comes with the "enter" - I tried cr, lf & crLf but none works. .sh will immediately end right after the "enter"

Comment: I think I am totally wrong! The input did not goes to .sh with standardinput.write or standardinput.writeline! I try to run below with input "y" with standardinput.writeline("y") and I got echo "no ::"
echo "Input(y/n):"
   read ans
    case $ans in
   n | "")
   echo no :$ans:;;
   y)
   echo yes;;
   *)
   echo other;;
   esac
I totally have no idea at all!